# What's Aatrox connection with Tryndamere?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes, when Aatrox meets Tryndamere, he says:

"Tryndamere, my greatest creation"

Why's that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have a connection in the lore. Well, but it's a little hard to read, though.

In [Tryndamere's lore](http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/tryndamere/#champion-lore) you can find a little hint on what has happened between them:

> (...)
>   Raiders ambushed Tryndamere's clan in the dead of night, (...), they
>   weren't prepared for the dark figure that next stepped forth. **He
>   wielded a cruel, living sword, *and inspired an unhinged bloodlust in
>   the invaders* with his unearthly magic.** Tryndamere's tribe was overrun
>   within moments. **With no hope of defeating the enigmatic being,
>   Tryndamere threw himself at certain death.** The dark figure swatted him
>   aside, mortally wounding the young barbarian.
>
> Tryndamere saw death and destruction engulf his home as his life
>   slipped away. No one was left standing - only the screams of the dying
>   remained. Unable to surrender to death, Tryndamere gave in fully to
>   his wrath. His blood boiled and his anger consumed him, banishing his
>   mortality. He staggered to his feet - barely able to take hold of his
>   sword - steeling himself for the decisive confrontation with the
>   shadowy being. But the dark figure did not even lift his blade, and
>   instead gave Tryndamere a knowing smile as he withdrew into the
>   shadows. That was the last time the barbarian ever saw his nemesis.

The following paragraph explains that Tryndamere wandered for years and fought every champion of a tribe to see his nemesis again til there was none left to challenge.

Nice! Then back in [Aatrox' lore](http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/aatrox/#champion-lore) there is another little hint on that cursive text in the last blockquote, where he inspired the invaders:

> Just when all hope seemed lost, Aatrox appeared among the ranks of the
>   Protectorate. With but a few words, he urged the soldiers to fight to
>   the last before throwing himself into battle. His presence inspired
>   the desperate warriors. At first, they could only watch in awe as this
>   unknown hero cleaved through their enemies, his body and blade moving
>   in unison as if one being. Soon, the warriors found themselves imbued
>   with a potent thirst for battle. They followed Aatrox into the fray,
>   each fighting with the furious strength of ten until they had won a
>   most unlikely victory.

There is even [a little forum discussion](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3556630) which is about Aatrox VS Tryndamere, claiming who will win, if Aatrox "swatted him aside, mortally wounding the young barbarian".

FYI: atrox (latin) means abhorrent, gruesome, dire.

Comment: Thanks for that. Had to google again to make sure these references are for Aatrox/Trannymere. :D